# JPanel: What is the simplest way to display an image?

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am working on a project and I need to display an image that I have already drawn. I need a background image and several foreground images that I can move around. What is the easiest way to do this? I haven't been able to find a clear answer.

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("imagename.jpg");
    JLabel label = new JLabel("", image, JLabel.CENTER);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    panel.add( label, BorderLayout.CENTER );
    return panel;
```

Comment: Post the code you already have.

Comment: *"I haven't been able to find a clear answer."*  What answers did you see?  Link to them.

Comment: I added my code. I know I need a file path, but what is the root? Is it C, the project, the file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Swing: how to add an image to a JPanel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299495/java-swing-how-to-add-an-image-to-a-jpanel)

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends.  Do you want to resize the background image to meet the requirements of the client are or not?  If so, do you want to "fill" or "fit" the image to the area.

Take a look at [Java: maintaining aspect ratio of JPanel background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928) for a lengthier discussion on the topic.

The next question you need to ask, is do you want to paint the animation on the surface or use existing components and move them instead...

You could check out...

- [Swing animation running extremely slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886232/swing-animation-running-extremely-slow/14902184#14902184)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858623/how-to-use-a-swing-timer-to-animate/15859932#15859932
- [Drawing 2 Balls to move in different direction on Java but one disappeared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352969/drawing-2-balls-to-move-in-different-direction-on-java-but-one-disappeared/15353052#15353052)
- [Java Bouncing Ball](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022754/java-bouncing-ball/13022788#13022788)
- [Multiple bouncing balls thread issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593678/multiple-bouncing-balls-thread-issue/14593761#14593761)
- [I am trying to make ball gradually move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15078835/i-am-trying-to-make-ball-gradually-move/15079240#15079240)
- [the images are not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12642852/the-images-are-not-loading/12648265#12648265)

Which uses the `paintComponent` or direct paint method.

This approach is relatively common and easy to control.  The problem is if you want to perform sub animation (ie animate the actually element separately from the main animation...think walking or spinning), then it becomes more difficult.

Check out

- [Java ball object doesn't bounce off of drawn rectangles like it's supposed to.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13261767/java-ball-object-doesnt-bounce-off-of-drawn-rectangles-like-its-supposed-to/13263022#13263022)

Which uses components instead.  This method is good if you want to provide sub animation, but has the complexity of requiring you to size and position the components within the container.

Just as a side note.  `JLabel` is a container ;)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way i've found is to create an entirely new class and extend JPanel like so:

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.imageio.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.awt.*;


    public class Background extends JPanel {

        private Image image;

        public Background(){
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,height));
            image =Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("your_image.jpg");;
        }
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            //paints the background image
            super.paintComponent(g);
            do{

            }while(g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null)==false);
        }
  }
```

To instantiate this class simply call this:

```
Background b= new Background();
```

From your main program.

Remember that b now acts as a Jpanel so you can simply call `b.add(element)`

If you don't understand what i've talked about and shown you, view this document on extending classes:

[Extending Classes](http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/java104/java104.html)

Comment: The do/while is unnecessary. Just specify the ImageObserver by using "this" instead of "null".